# How to inject multiple module dependencies into Dagger-2 components?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, dagger-2

Within my root component's modules I regularly use components to return/provide separate object graphs within my container. *What's the best way to initiate the components/object graphs with existing module dependencies?* 
I feel like I should use subcomponents here, but have no clue how. Preferably I want to initiate the component with all components that are available up to this point. Currently I pass every single instance via the Builder and @BindsInstance mechanism to the component builder, which seems pretty awkward, but I'm not aware of a better design:

**Root component**

```
@Component(includes = TradeModule.class)
public interface RootComponent{
   ...
   ...
}
```

**My module**

```
@Module
public class TradeModule{

@Provides
@Singleton
//this is one example dependency that I want to inject in the component below
TimeframePermissionEvaluator timeframePermissionEvaluator() {
    return new TimeframePermissionEvaluator();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
TradeModel tradeModel(TradeModelComponent.Builder builder, //assume builder is available
                      TimeframePermissionEvaluator tpe) {
    return builder
         //here I inject the dependency into the component. What's a more elegant 
         //way to do this? Imagine I have to inject hundreds of dependencies of TradeModule
        .timeframePermissionEvaluator(tpe) 
        .build()
        .createTradeModel();
}
}
```